# The textarea element in Vue or Nuxt throws a message to the console by default

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, dom-events, nuxt.js

This message appears in the console whenever I use a **textarea** html element in a Vue/cli or Nuxt projects.

What can I do to prevent this message from appearing in the console?

```html
<textarea  rows="5" cols="33">
     This is a textarea.
</textarea>
```

Console:

> Textarea 727bd34788820fe9 ready. contentscript.js:1

If I type a word in that element:

> Remarks accepted (727bd34788820fe9):0 contentscript.js:1

Comment: This sounds like it's coming from an extension. Try disabling your extensions and see if the issue persists

Comment: Do you have a [repro] for this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **spellcheck** attribute of textarea can be read in this [MDN document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/spellcheck):

> true, which indicates that the element should be, if possible, checked for spelling errors;

> false, which indicates that the element should not be checked for spelling errors.

> If this attribute is not set, its default value is element-type and browser-defined.

If there is a textarea, the anonymous messages can be seen in the console dev tools if a spellchecker extension like Becorrect is installed on Chrome (or another browser).

This messages will not appear if the spellcheck value is set to false or if the extension is disabled.